# Redirect requests to base folder to subfolder but leave rest alone

Tags: apache, http, redirect

How do I do this on my apache host?

Want to rewrite all requests like https://www.example.com and    http://www.example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com to    subfolder /forum

Leave all other requests alone, so something like    [www.example.com/wiki](http://www.example.com/wiki) will still goto /wiki folder

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out if anyone needs it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```